# Dynamically allocating a vector C

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand the concept of dynamically allocating a `struct´ in C, also I am interested in generic dynamically allocating, could you give me some help or information about this topic?

I've managed to understand the concept of pointers and I managed to to some kind of code but I am not sure if is right or if it's working as it should be...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    typedef struct {
        int id;
        char nume[20];
    } pers;

    pers *i = malloc(sizeof(pers)*100);

    i->id=22;
    i++;
    i->id=33;
}
```

My question is, have I declared this array properly, how do I print an element of this array, how do I refer to a specific element for eq. `i[9]`, and is there another way to do the same thing? I've heard about generic dynamically allocating memory, could someone give me an eq. of that?

Comment: i[9] = *(i+9) = *(9+i) = 9[i] by standard definition

Comment: It's usual to define structures outside the functions. Here between the includes and main.

Comment: You shouldn't really change i, because you'll lose track of the beginning of the array. You'll need this to free the memory later.

Comment: You need to check `i` is non NULL before using it, in case `malloc` fails for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would do the `typedef struct` before (outside) the function but it works.

Your allocation is correct.

But `i++` makes no sense here. You should keep the pointer `i` so that you still know where the allocated memory starts. What you probably want is another pointer into the array, and increase that:

```
pers* it = i;
it->id=22;
printf("%d", it->id);
it++;
it->id=33;
printf("%d", it->id);
```

Comment: typedefs can have block scope ever since; it's mildly unusual but guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Jens I know. Yes, unusual.

Answer (score 4):

When you do `i++` you loose the original pointer. Instead you can use normal array indexing:

```
i[0].id = 22;
i[1].id = 33;
```

You need the original pointer when you later want to free the allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

All of the following are synonyms:

`*(i + 9)`

`*(9 + i)`

`i[9]`

`9[i]`

Comment: Ok, and if i want to swipe between the elements could i do something like this for(int j=0;j<100,j++){i[j]->id=0} for making all the elements  id's 0 ?

Comment: What is 9[i] supposed to be?

Comment: @QuentinUK : it's *(9 + i). Really bad style, but legal.

Comment: @JackRobinson Of course you can, just that it's `i[j].id` instead of `i[j]->id`, because `i` is a pointer, but `i[j]` in turn is an object.

Answer (score 2):

You refer to an element in the dynamically allocated array the same way you would refer to an element in an automatic array.

Using `pers[i]` will refer to the ith element. To access a field such as `id` you would use `pers[i].id`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change the pointer that malloc returned you. Treat it like a constant to avoid creating a *memory leak* (allocating and losing the pointer to the allocated memory).
Instead of modifying `i`, iterate using a new index variable, let's call it `j`:
To clear/initialize all array elements:

```
#include <string.h> /* for memset(). */
int j;
for (j=0; j<100; ++j) {
  i[j].id = 0;
  memset (i[j].nume, 0, 20); /* Or sizeof(i[0].nume) instead of 20. */
}
```

To print all array elements:

```
for (j=0; j<100; ++j) {
  printf ("id[%d] = %d\n", j, i[j].id);
  printf ("nume[%d] = '%s'\n", j, i[j].nume);
}
```

I would also suggest to rename `i` to `person`; this makes the code so much more readable.

Comment: Why not memset( i, 0 , 100*sizeof(pers)) instead of manually initializing all fields?

Comment: Because that makes it harder to initialize different elements or members with different values depending on index. The OP is likely more interested in how to process individual objects than exactly one special case where all zeros are what is wanted. What's more, if the struct contained pointers (it doesn't here), all zeros is not good to initialize pointers to NULL.